# Hide default fullscreen button on react-google-maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with react-google-maps.

I created my own button for FullScreen toggle

[image]

I have tried but can't find the way to get rid of the default button.
I tried to add this to my code, but it didn't work.

```
<GoogleMap
 ref={(map) => console.log()}
 defaultZoom={12}
 defaultCenter={{ lat: this.state.lat, lng: this.state.lng }}
 fullscreenControl={false}
>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just to include it in default options

```
const defaultMapOptions = {
  fullscreenControl: false,
};

const InputGoogleMap = withGoogleMap(props=>(
  <GoogleMap
    ref={(map) => console.log()}
    defaultZoom={12}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: this.state.lat, lng: this.state.lng }}
    defaultOptions={defaultMapOptions}
  />
))
```

For more Google Maps options you can find it here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#MapOptions

Comment: Please, edit this answer, updating the new API parameter. `defaultOptions` was replaced by `options`.

Answer (score 20):

I think library got an update: `google-map-react 0.23`

`defaultOptions` changed to `options`

```
const mapOptions = {
  fullscreenControl: false,
};

const Map = withGoogleMap(props=>(
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={12}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: this.state.lat, lng: this.state.lng }}
    options={mapOptions}
  />
))
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 4):

Above both solutions were not working for me. Since I was using some custom styles along with the above styles. This removes both the full screen and the zoom in and zoom out buttons

```
const waterStyle = [
{
  featureType: "water",
  elementType: "geometry.fill",
  stylers: [
    {
      color: "#4BB4F5",
    },
  ],
},]

 <GoogleMap
    defaultCenter={{ lat: 0, lng: 0 }}
    defaultZoom={3}
    options={{
      styles: waterStyle,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
    }}
  >
```

If you want to only hide the full-screen button you use: Zoom in and out buttons can be visible and used

```
 <GoogleMap
    defaultCenter={{ lat: 0, lng: 0 }}
    defaultZoom={3}
    options={{
      styles: waterStyle,
      fullscreenControl: false,
    }}
  >
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions worked, I have the 2.0.6 version of google-maps-react. It worked, however with passing down as props.

Example:

```
<GoogleMap
defaultCenter={{ lat: 0, lng: 0 }}
defaultZoom={3}
fullscreenControl: false,
>
```

Answer (score -3):

We need hide the icon and disable click event:

```
.gmnoprint.gm-style-cc + button,
.gm-fullscreen-control {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Library has a prop you can pass, disabling via css is not a valid solution and can lead to bugs.

Answer (score -4):

Nah, my mate solved it, just target the class instead of trying to hide it with the props

```
.gm-fullscreen-control {
 display: none!important;
}
```

Comment: Why should you disable it with a class name? What if the class name changes in another version? and since the library provides a solution why use a hack?